# displaying several pictures from a shared File

Tags: c#, xaml

Here is 2lines that display pictures from my projects folder Assets in

```
String path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Assets";
myFlipView.ItemsSource = Directory.GetFiles(path).Select(p => "ms-appx:///"+ p);
```

in the same idea I would like to add several pictures to my flipView  but it's in a shared file

myFlipView.ItemsSource = Directory.GetFiles(http://localhost/Pictures).
Pictures is a Folder that contain Pictures and their numbers can change
how can I add it to myFlipView.ItemsSource

Answer (score 0):

```
as getFiles implements ILISt as long as the method GetFiles returns a list of strings for example I did that 



List<string> myPathListPictures=new List<string>();
myPathListPictures = GetPictures();
fv.ItemsSource = myPathListPictures.Select(p=> "Http://localhost" + p);
```